# The property a(bc)=(ab)c for linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let a,b,c be linear operators. Is the property (ab)c=a(bc) correct? Could you show me how to prove it?

Comment: There is no difference whether you first (send x to y and then y to z) and then send z to t, or first send x to y and then (send y to z and then send z to t). The result is always that x goes to t.

Comment: Represent them as matrices and prove associativity for matrix multiplication

Comment: @DoubleAA, that's a bit overkill. To define bases, matrices, possibly infinite dimensional, sums, matrix multiplications etc.. just to show something that holds for any maps?

Comment: @PeterFranek Perhaps, though it is likely the OP has proved associativity of matrix multiplication at some point in the past (probably in the first few weeks of 1st semester linear algebra)

Answer (score 1):

Linear operators are functions and multiplication is given by composition. Function composition is easily seen to be associative.

Namely, define $(ab)(y)=a(b(y))$ and $(bc)(y)=b(c(y))$. Then $(ab)(c(x))=a(b(c(x)))=a((bc)(x))$.

Comment: Indeed. For matrices of finite size at least, it’s easier to use this obviously true principle to show associativity of matrix multiplication, than to get yourself tangled up in the mess of indices.